# Integral $ \int \frac{\operatorname d\!x}{\sin^3 x} $

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integral $\int \frac {1}{\sin^3(x)} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258754/integral-int-frac-1-sin3x-dx)

Can someone help me compute $$\int \frac {1}{\sin^3 x } dx $$

Thanks !

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsin%5E3+x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:*

employ the [Weierstraß substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $t=\tan (x/2)$ to bring the integral into a form of a rational function. Note that $\sin x= 2t/(1+t^2)$, $dx = 2 dt/(1+t^2)$, so
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sin^3 x} =  \int \frac{(1+t^2)^2}{4 t^3} dt .$$

You can reduce the order by the substitution $u=t^2 =\tan^2 (x/2) =(1-\cos x)/(1+\cos x)$, which yields
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sin^3 x} = \int \frac{(1+u)^2}{8u^2} du
= \int \frac{du}{8} + \int\frac{du}{4u} + \int\frac{du}{8 u^2} .$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks !

Comment: @theMissingIngredient: if the answer did help you, don't forget to accept the answer (and potentially upvote it). Do so also for the other questions which you have asked...

Comment: Its the same integral as $$\int{csc^3(x)dx} $$ easy integration by parts

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way $$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^3 x}=\int\frac{\sin x dx}{\sin^4 x}=-\int\frac{d(\cos x)}{(1-\cos^2 x)^2}=-\int\frac{dz}{(1+z)^2 (1-z)^2}$$ Now this can be calculated using method of partial fractions.